# How can I indicate loading on a long form submit that ends in a file download?

Tags: javascript, loading

I have an HTML form that when submitted generates a PDF and prompts the user to download it.

The PDF might take a little while to generate. I would like to present the user with a loading indicator while this is happening, so they know the system is working. Once they get the download prompt (or auto download starts), I would like the indicator to disappear

Is there a way to do this, or do I have to write clever JS to generate in the background and monitor for completion? Adding a loading gif on submit is easy, but the gif just pauses so it's not really useful and I can't figure out how to tell when it should clear either.

Answer (score 1):

[Romanych's Wait-for-download](https://github.com/romanych/wait-for-download) should help, at least the part of the source code you're interested in.

Comment: That just opens a popup window to do the download in, which is what I am trying to avoid. If I wanted to work around it, I would generate the file in the background and have loading until the files ready, then present it to them. I am wondering if there is a more elegant way than doing this.